# How to make the Close button disabled in a windows Form using C# coding

Tags: c#, windows

every one. I just want to make the Close button disabled on a button click event using C#.net. I am trying for this but not correctly sure it's correct.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ControlBox = false;
    }
```

Comment: Just FYI ControlBox is the top-left icon, not the close button

Comment: You could easily find this on the web: http://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+disable+close+button&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1&redir_esc=&ei=YKSdTZaML4-fOuPvpdQE First hit already shows an example.

Comment: Why don't you handle it in the Form closing event

Comment: no, i want to make it on a button click, if i use in form closing then i will be unable to close the form.

Comment: By the way, someone will ALWAYS be able to close a form.  If you remove the close button, you can use the control box.  If you remove that, you can use Alt+F4.  If you remove that, you can right-click the taskbar and select 'Close'.  If you remove that, you can use Task Manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private const int dis_close_button = 0x200;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams ObjCP = base.CreateParams;
            ObjCP.ClassStyle = ObjCP.ClassStyle | dis_close_button;
            return ObjCP;
        }
    }
```

Try, this...

Answer (score 1):

Add the following library

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Declare the following as class level variable

```
const int MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;

[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("User32")]
private static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hWnd);
```

In the Form_Load() event, write the following code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
        int menuItemCount = GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
        RemoveMenu(hMenu, menuItemCount - 1, MF_BYPOSITION);
```

}

[Disable the Close 'X' button](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/itsraj007/Rajendra105292008020242AM/Rajendra1.aspx)

Just modify it for your ClickEvent