# How to make a Close button in a form disabled

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the Close button disabled in a windows Form using C# coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580512/how-to-make-the-close-button-disabled-in-a-windows-form-using-c-coding)

I want to disable Close button in a form can any one help me in this.

Comment: OK, we need a bunch more information here. Are you working in WinForms, WPF, Silverlight or ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you mean the button at the top right with the 'x'?

Comment: voting to close as duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580512/how-to-make-the-close-button-disabled-in-a-windows-form-using-c-coding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetSystemMenu(int hwnd, int revert);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int GetMenuItemCount(int menu);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int RemoveMenu(int menu, int position, int flags);

private void DisableCloseButton()
{
   int menu = GetSystemMenu(Handle.ToInt32(), 0);
   int count = GetMenuItemCount(menu);
   RemoveMenu(menu, count - 1, MF_DISABLED | MF_BYPOSITION);
}
```